# setup:di:compile in the different modes

Tags: magento2, compiler, setup-di-compile

I'm trying to understand how compilation works in Magento 2 with regards to default mode, developer mode, and production mode.

The docs state that auto compilation is enabled in developer mode, which I assume negates the need to run setup:di:compile? In default mode, I'm not sure how compilation is handled. For production mode, I assume you need to re-run setup:di:compile if changes are made for those to materialize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't run `setup:di:compile` or clean `var/di`, DI will work same in all mode. If you run setup:di:compile and enable production mode, DI will get information from compiled files from `var/di`.

Answer (score 1):

Theorically you don't need (and you shouldn't) to run `setup:di:compile` when in developer mode. However, once you do that, Magento will generate the compiled classes under `/generated/code` (`/var/generated` in older versions). You can delete the content under `generated/code/*` and `generated/metadata/*` at any time (when in developer mode).

When you enable the production mode, the compilation will start automatically (unless --skip-generation is passed to `deploy:mode:set`).

You can find more information on the links below:

- [About Magento Modes (Magento DevDocs)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html)
- [Modos de Deploy: O que são e como usá-los? (**in Portuguese**)](https://magenteiro.com/blog/magento-2/modos-de-deploy-o-que-sao-e-como-usa-los/)